# How to print from an Android pos device

Tags: android, printing, pos

I have a pax a930 device with  android os v 7.0, and I want to write an app for this device. my app will test pax's printer
I tested usb,bluetooth,wifi printing codes and it did not work.
how can I print a text with this device?

http://smartwebindonesia.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Pax-a910-2-min-272x182.jpg

Comment: Perhaps the technical support here is relevant, so please ask. [SUPPORT](https://www.pax.com.cn/support/index.aspx)

Comment: @kunif I asked for support, but they did not answer yet

Comment: i don't know why you get negative , i hope you can found the soloution

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

This sample project works on Pax A910 :

https://github.com/AnilMH/Android-studio-bluetooth-printer